# split function in x86 asm (loop over characters of a string)

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

So, I need split a string character by character

in JavaScript it will be like this

```js
let text = "abcde";
for (var i = 0; i < text.lenght; i++);
{
    console.log(text.charAt(i));
}
```

but how to do this is in NASM?

I am not an expert in assembly, but I have already tried to solve this problem for a week

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I made a function for quick output and on the calculation of the length of the message I tried to output a character
https://pastebin.com/nEBzNqnu

Comment: What convention do you use for representing strings?  If you don't know the answer to this question, just show us your code you use for defining a string and working with it.

Comment: @СашенькаГлинин you should add that into the answer! (As code, not as a link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I would not precisely call it 'splitting' a string, but rather **iterating** over a string.*

### In the data section

Define your string and make it zero-terminated:

```
MyText db 'abcde', 0
```

### In the code section

Establish a pointer to the beginning of the string:

```
    mov  esi, MyText
```

Read a byte from memory:

```
Again:
    mov  al, [esi]
```

Test to see if it is the terminating zero:

```
    test al, al
```

Stop the loop if it is indeed the end-of-string marker:

```
    jz   Done
```

Output the byte in AL any way you like:

```
    ...
```

Increment the pointer:

```
    inc  esi
```

Go repeat reading a byte:

```
    jmp  Again
Done:
```

Comment: Nitpick: the Javascript original that the OP cites enumerates over UTF-16 halfwords (or UCS-2 characters), not over bytes. That said, the OP seems like they are at the level where they don't care.

Comment: I get a Segmentation fault on the output, most likely it's the output that I'm doing, sorry for my stupidity, but could you send me the full code?

Comment: At the ellipsis, you could write: `mov edx, 1` `mov ecx, esi` `mov ebx, 1` `mov eax, 4` `int 0x80` to output the current character from the string on the screen.